# Excel -- Value Separation & New Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that contains more than one sheet, the outcome I am trying to achieve is to display the Recording Fee for a county based on a Zip Code. Some Zip Codes contain more than one county which are display as so

```
Cortland|Onondaga
```

I am trying to achieve where excel will separate the two or more values enter them on new rows and then fetch the recording fee based on the county name and state, where this is all done after the user submits a zip code on A2

Below is a link of the spreadsheet.

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/1M0A7n4xrrlCT6q65qvNPXgYQtVzHWHxS/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share more data along with expected output !!

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you need a list of the counties in the county string placed in the B2:B11 range using the Zip Code entered in A2 as the lookup value that obtains the county string, and then you can have a `VLOOKUP()` in D2:D11 using the B2:b11 values as the lookup values outputting the recording fee for each listed county and similarly have the same thing looking up additional page fees.

All that is easy enough including the handling of cells in B2:B11 being blank. I leave that to you since it is literally cookie-cutter and since you are only asking about the listing.

Going with your picture of how things look to the max extent, adding the Zip Code to Counties table as H1:I1, the following formula will get you the desired list:

```
=LET(LookupInput,  A2,
     LookupTable,  H1:I1,
     LookupColumn,  2,
     CountyDelimiter,  "|",
     ZipCodeCounties,  VLOOKUP(LookupInput,  LookupTable,  LookupColumn,  FALSE),
     Counties,  SEQUENCE(  LEN(ZipCodeCounties)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(ZipCodeCounties,CountyDelimiter,"")  )+1,   1),
     XMLString,  "<Outer><Inner>"&  SUBSTITUTE(ZipCodeCounties,  "|",  "</Inner><Inner>")  &"</Inner></Outer>",

     FILTERXML(XMLString,  "/Outer/Inner["&  Counties  &"]")
     )
```

The organization for the `LET()` is:

1. First, your three Data Input variables for the `VLOOKUP()`. At the absolute start so they are fast to find and edit. And a fourth to specify the delimiter in case your source would change that some day.
2. Interim calculation Names, the ones that do the `VLOOKUP()` using the Zip Code to get the string you need parsed and that figures out how many elements there are to parse out of it.
3. The last required interim Name, the one that formats the county string as an HTML string so `FILTERXML()` can use it.
4. The actual working formula, using Names from the defined ones (mentioned in 1-3, above). Notice it straightforward to read and understand rather than a tight, dense, mess.

Basically the formula takes the input Zip Code and looks up the county string. It then renders that string as HTML and also calculates how many elements there are in it by finding its length at the start, and its length with its delimiters removed, subtracting to find out how many were removed, then adding one (one delimiter between each element means that many elements plus one more so...). Finally, it uses `FILTERXML()` to return each of the elements by using the function normally, but giving it a request for each element, rather than asking for a single one, or all of them at once. It uses `SEQUENCE()` and the count of elements it made to fuel that.

Doing that last bit, passing it the string of element requests using `SEQUENCE()` is not necessary and you can just remove that and the supporting interim calculation above it if you like. Simpler, and faster, if that were of interest though it almost never is anymore. The reason I put them in was to give you a "hook" into dealing with the number of counties in the list exceeding what you have space for in B2:B11. Again though, you can just remove it and it will work identically. In real life, you probably face having to adjust the recording fee and additional page fee lookups for empty cells in that range, not worry about needing more lines than you've reserved, but I put it in just in case.

(`FILTERXML()` works in 2013 onward. If you are using an earlier version, you will need to use a different one of several techniques for parsing strings, all of which, as I recall, use {CSE} entry. If using a version without `SEQUENCE()`, you can just delete its elements from the formula, or use the old ROW(1:xxx) method of generating a variable-length array.)